# Creating a battlefield grid in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to build a battlefield made of 10x10 grid.

Below is my code:

```
SHIP_HASH = { submarine: 2, destroyer: 3, destroyer: 3, cruiser: 4, aircraftcarrier: 5,}

def print_results
  board_layout = Array.new(10, " ").map{|row| Array.new(10, " ")}
  row_label = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
  column_label = [" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
end

print print_results
```

I received the output:

`[" ", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]`

What I wanted is to generate an output like below but I dunno know what's the error.

         `0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9
    0    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    . 
    1    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
    2    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
    3    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
    4    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
    5    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
    6    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
    7    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
    8    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
    9    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .`

Comment: You don't even have any dots in your code, how do you expect them to get printed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So in ruby, the last thing evaluated in a method is what is returned.  So in your `print results`, the last thing evaluated is the assignment of `column_label` which is what you see is returned.

Here is the code, note the use of `print` in some cases and `puts` in others as they do different things:

```
SHIP_HASH = { submarine: 2, destroyer: 3, destroyer: 3, cruiser: 4, aircraftcarrier: 5,}

def print_results
  board_layout = Array.new(10, ".").map{|row| Array.new(10, ".")}
  row_label = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]
  column_label = ["0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"]

  print "\t"
  print row_label.join("\t")
  puts
  board_layout.each_with_index do |row, i|
    print column_label[i]
    print "\t"
    print row.join("\t")
    puts
  end
end

print_results
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
0   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
1   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
2   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
3   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
4   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
5   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
6   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
7   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
8   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
9   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
```

Let me know if you have any questions on that.

Comment: What if I removed the brackets and the `" "` in order to make it look neater? I tried using `board_layout = Array.new(10, ".").map{|row| Array.new(10, ".")}` but it doesn't come out the way I wanted it to. I changed the intended output in my first post so to give you an idea of what I would like to generate. @anthony

Comment: I dont understand why you have to type out `print"\t"` and also `print row_label.join("\t")` @anthony

Comment: `print "\t"` inserts a tab character, it's how I'm aligning everything.  `row.join("\t")` is taking the array and putting it into a string where each element is also separated by a tab character.

Comment: I get it now. Currently, the next thing I would like to perform is placing the ships of different lengths randomly on the grid. Any tips on how I could achieve that? @anthony